# MySQL: Whole database, convert [empty] values to NULL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a database where there is a mix of `NULL` and `''` (empty) values. I would like to convert all empty values to `NULL`.

**Something like**

```
UPDATE table SET col=NULL WHERE col=''
```

**but for the whole database**

---

notes:

- I've changed default values to NULL
- I'm well aware of the NULL vs '' debate, and this isn't something i really want to go into (plenty of other questions on SO for that)

Comment: How many tables are there? Is there a reason you can't just copy/paste the above statement and change the table name for each table? If there's no good reason to get complicated...don't.

Comment: What @Justin says. This can probably be done using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` but if it's not a recurring task, do a quick copy&paste

Comment: 15 tables x approx 7 applicable columns each ? 100 search and replaces....

Comment: Would it not be applicable to create a new table and default col to `NULL` then `INSERT INTO table_two (x,x,x,x) VALUES (SELECT x,x,x,x FROM table_one)` ? something along them lines, just leaving out col so it defaults to NULL.

Comment: ah bugger it, i'll write a php script that gets the column names for each table and then updates empty values

Comment: Robert - I think some of his values are non-empties, and he only wants to convert the ones that are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$tables = {array of table names};

foreach($tables as $t){
    $cols = FALSE;
    $q = "SELECT * FROM $t LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysql_query($q);
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)){    
        $cols = array_keys($r);
    }
    if($cols){
        foreach($cols as $c){
            $q2 = "UPDATE $t SET $c=NULL WHERE $c = ''";
            mysql_query($q2);
            echo mysql_error();
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There probably is a better solution, but you could always do a mysql dump of the base, and then parse the .sql file, replacing '' with NULL. For parsing, you could use custom made php script, or some other way - that part shouldn't be hard :)

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way might just be to dump, search/replace using a text editor, then load.